# Were the works of Greek and Roman thinkers available to the West during the Middle Ages?

Tags: history, history-of-science

The conventional wisdom, repeated recently in [How the Middle Ages Really Were](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/quora/how-the-middle-ages-reall_b_5767240.html), claims (the quote is "composite"):

> ...the works of Greek and Roman thinkers like Aristotle, Galen, Ptolemy, Archimedes and many others had been lost in the West after the collapse of the Roman Empire...
>   ...Medieval scholars learned those works because they were preserved by the Arabs...

Even when Rome fell (two centuries before the Arab conquest began), Constantinople remained and should have preserved at least the major works, and the land communications of Europe with the Arabs went through it anyway.

Were these works "lost" to the West, and only preserved by Arabs?

Comment: Your famous quote first appeared in book by a Christian 500 years after the fact.  Since there is great skepticism about how believable it is, I'm not sure what its adding.

Comment: This question would be much better on our History site than on Skeptics. It's a nuanced, multifaceted question about history, that would benefit from a history expert.

Comment: @DJClayworth I agree.  There is a good [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_of_the_Greek_Classics) which directly answers the question, and I could summarize it.  But somebody on the History site might have better insights than my summary of wikipedia.

Comment: @DJClayworth: the reason I am asking it here and not on History is that I am, apparently, challenging an accepted narrative. Please feel free to move my question there.

Comment: If there is a widely accepted view espoused by history experts, well documented and supported, then that's going to be the answer here too.

Comment: @DJClayworth: yes, of course.  I am skeptical about the "conventional wisdom" and I am asking for the "widely accepted view espoused by history experts, well documented and supported".

Comment: There is no way we can answer this with facts, as it's not really factual. It hinges on how literally we want to take "lost". If there were 10 copies of a book left, were they "lost"? Does the author mean there were absolutely no copies left?